# Binding DateTime to TimePicker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: datetime, xamarin.forms, type-conversion, timespan

I tried to bind a DateTime value to a TimePicker instead of a TimeSpan.
If I change the Datatype then I have to change my complete code.

The property is called Item.Time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" Title="New Item">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
            <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
            <TimePicker Time="{Binding Item.Time}"/>
            <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Editor Text="{Binding Item.Text}" FontSize="Small" Margin="0" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How can I convert DateTime to TimeSpan without using an other class or something like that?

Is it possible to convert it with code like this:

```
<TimePicker Time="{Binding **(TimeSpan)**Item.Time}"/>
```

Comment: you could probably do this with a ValueConverter

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this without the help of any other class, so you will need to convert it in your ViewModel already and expose it as a property and use that.

This would simply mean something like:

```
public TimeSpan MyTimeSpan
{
    get { return Item.Time; } // Assuming Item.Time is a TimeSpan
    set { Item.Time = value; }
}
```

You could also use a value converter. To do this, create a new class which implements the `IValueConverter` interface. It should be something like this, note that this is pseudo-code from the top of my head and might not work out of the box:

```
public class DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((DateTime)value).Time;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var incomingTimeSpan = (TimeSpan)value;
        return new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, incomingTimeSpan.Hours, incomingTimeSpan.Minutes, incomingTimeSpan.Seconds);
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you can use it like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceName"...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter x:Key="timeSpanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
    <TimePicker Time="{Binding Item.Time, Converter={StaticResource timeSpanConverter}}"/>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Read more on value converters in the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Answer (score 1):

You can get TimeStamp value from DataTime object, like "DataTimeObject.TimeOfDay", The TimeOfDay is a TimeStamp datatype.

```
         <TimePicker x:Name="Timepicker"  HeightRequest="100" Time="{Binding 
          Item.TimeOfDay, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          PropertyChanged="TimePicker_PropertyChanged"/>
```

Comment: Hi Tom_Vel, that you know is possible to have on same page a DatePicker (for date part) and a TimePicker (for time part) that binds to same property?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same property for DatePicker and TimePicker.

Comment: should be accepted answer IMHO

Comment: If you want to be able to set Time in your ViewModel property, this will not work, because TimeOfDay has no setter.  This code is invalid, you can't have TwoWay Binding on this property

Answer (score 0):

Either use a value converter or add a TimeSpan property to your view model

Answer (score 0):

A straight to the point example compiled from @GeraldVersluis example. Note that I have two controls "ReturnTime" and "ReturnDate":

```
 DateTime d = this.ReturnDate.Date;
 DateTime dtCombined = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, ReturnTime.Time.Hours, this.ReturnTime.Time.Minutes, this.ReturnTime.Time.Seconds);
```